# Change Qtabwidget text according to the Qtwebview it contains

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qtabwidget

I have Qtabwiget And everytime I load another tab it loads an instance of an Qtwebengineview class. What I need is when the every instance of qtwebengine finish loading it change the parent tab of it instead what i have which changes the current opened tab. here is the code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 75, self.sizeObject.width(), self.sizeObject.height() - 120))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

    def loadFinished(self, ok):
        self.progressBar.hide()
        >>>I want here to be able to change parent qtabwidget text to the title of the qtwebengineview child<<<


class HtmlView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HtmlView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.parent.loadFinished)
```

Comment: `self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.sender())`.

Comment: If you dont mind, Can you explain more about what happens with this code? because I guess you misunderstood me because I wasn't so clear. what i want is to set the tab text to the qwebengine title of the current page that is inside this tab.

Comment: I have something like this now which doesn't work. `def loadFinished(self, ok):
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.sender())
        self.progressBar.hide()
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.currentWidget().parent(), self.tabWidget.currentWidget().title())`

Comment: Solved, with the help of your comment i solved my issue :).